# how to clear react hook dynamically?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

i have this input hook:

```
export const Use_Input_Hook = (initial_value: string) => {
  const [value, set_value] = useState(initial_value);
  return {
    value,
    set_value,
    reset: () => set_value(''),
    bind: {
      value,
      onChange: (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
        set_value(e.target.value);
      }
    }
  };
};
```

I want to use it dynamically in a form like this, but how can i reset it on submit?

```
{['Name', 'Email', 'Age'].map(form_input_key => {
          const { value, bind, reset } = Use_Input_Hook('');
          return (
            <FormGroup row>
              <Label for='exampleEmail' sm={2}>
                {form_input_key}
              </Label>
              <Col sm={10}>
                <Input
                  type='email'
                  name='email'
                  id='exampleEmail'
                  {...bind}
                  placeholder='with a placeholder'
                />
              </Col>
            </FormGroup>
          );
        })}
```

or do i have to manually do it like this:

```
const { value:firstName, bind:bindFirstName, reset:resetFirstName } = Use_Input_Hook('');
  const { value:lastName, bind:bindLastName, reset:resetLastName } = Use_Input_Hook('');

  const handleSubmit = (evt) => {
      evt.preventDefault();
      alert(`Submitting Name ${firstName} ${lastName}`);
      resetFirstName();
      resetLastName();
  }
```

Comment: Hooks can only be called from whitin components or other hooks. You're calling it from inside a `map`

Comment: @Dupocas i'm new in hooks and thinking of best ways, i edited the question.